# Issue with attaching PDF files using Excel VBA and Gmail API - Incomplete file upload

Tags: excel, vba, gmail, gmail-api, email-attachments

I am currently using Excel VBA and the Gmail API to create email drafts and attach files to them. The code works, but I am facing an issue where the attached file is uploaded incompletely, resulting in an unreadable file. For example, if the original file size is 350 KB, the uploaded file size becomes 349 KB.

I have tried different approaches to attach the file, including appending the file content directly to the attachment payload. However, I haven't been able to find a reliable solution to ensure the proper upload and attachment of the file.

Here is a snippet of the code I am currently using for creating the email message and attaching the file:

```
' Construct the email message
Dim message As String
message = "To: " & recipient & vbCrLf
message = message & "Subject: " & subject & vbCrLf
message = message & "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=foo_bar_baz" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
message = message & "--foo_bar_baz" & vbCrLf
message = message & "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
message = message & "Dear " & position & " " & lastName & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
message = message & emailBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

            
                ' Attach the PDF file to the draft
                Dim folderPath As String
                folderPath = wb.Path & "\" & folderNum
                
                Dim fileName As String
                fileName = "Attachment.pdf"
                
                Dim attachmentPayload As String
                attachmentPayload = "--foo_bar_baz" & vbCrLf
                attachmentPayload = attachmentPayload & "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=""" & fileName & """" & vbCrLf
                attachmentPayload = attachmentPayload & "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                
                Dim fileContent() As Byte
                fileContent = ReadBinaryFile(folderPath & "\" & fileName)
                
                ' Append the file content directly to the attachment payload
                attachmentPayload = attachmentPayload & BytesToBinary(fileContent) & vbCrLf
                attachmentPayload = attachmentPayload & "--foo_bar_baz--"
                
                ' Add the attachment to the email message
                message = message & attachmentPayload

            
                 ' Always create a new draft email
                    draftStatus = CreateDraftEmail(accessToken, recipient, subject, message)
```

Is there a way to modify this code or find an alternative approach to ensure that the attached file is uploaded properly without any data loss? I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code examples that can help me resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!